# Do Back4App or Firebase Support Java Hosting?

Tags: java

I have an account with Heroku, which has a free Java hosting service, but I've noticed that it clears up all my saved files on a daily basis, because it's a free account.

So I did some search online and tried to find similar free Java hosting services, I know about Google App Engine and AWS, not interested in them because GAE use it's own Java package, and AWS only have 12 month free option.

Then I found Back4App and Firebase, but from their sites I can't tell if they support free Java hosting, if I have a xyz.war file, can I upload to them and get my online app running ?

Is there any other sites that offer limited free Java hosting like Heroku but don't delete my data on a daily basis ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use Back4app to host your application. They have a documentation regarding to JAVA that can help you about their integration.
I don't know about Firebase, but I know that you can create a free account and there's a free plan on Back4app (without any expiration date). Each 30 days the plan is restarted and you can use your project without any trouble.
NOTE: The cloud code doesn't support JAVA, so, if you need to use it, you will have to write your functions in Javascript. :)